# print factor without line numbers and levels in r

Tags: r

Is there a way to print a factor without the line numbers and its levels in R?

For example I tried:

`Input: print(as.factor("Male"), max.levels = 0)
 Output: [1] Male`

I read on Stackoverflow that using `cat()` suppresses the line number but that doesn't seem to work here.

`Input: cat(print(as.factor("Male"), max.levels = 0))
 Output: [1] Male
        1`

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: use `as.character`?

Comment: I realized this question was extremely stupid. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to see just the factor levels you can use the code:

`levels(data_frame$field)`.

That will show you all of the factor levels without the rows or observations.